# NSLog - Write word in singular if condition is met

Tags: objective-c, command-line, nslog

I'm writing a single command line program in Objective-C after writing it in Java. In one sentence I need to change a word depending on a number, if the number is 1, the word must be in singular otherwise, it should be in plural. In Java I can do that with

```
System.out.println"Hello" + (num = 1 ? "singular" : "plural");
```

How can I do something similar in Objective-C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the same exact trick in Objective C:

```
NSLog(@"Hello %@", num == 1 ? @"singular" : @"plural");
```

Comment: Oh, thank you! I didn't know about the @ so I wasn't able to do it!